# _co.gotoArchivePage is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am quite new to ionic and I am trying to develop a todo application in ionic version 3.9. I tried creating a fab button which would lead me to a “ArchiveTodos” Page, but each time I click on the fab button I get this result:

```
Error

  Runtime Error
  co.gotoArchivePage is not a function
  Stack
  TypeError: _co.gotoArchivePage is not a function
 at Object.eval [as handleEvent] 
    (ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:152:31)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13963:155)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15472:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] 
    (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15059:12)...
```

Environment:

```
    Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
    Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.11
    Angular Core: 5.2.11
    Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
    Node: 8.9.3
    OS Platform: Windows 10
    Navigator Platform: Win32
    User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68... Safari/537.36
```

home.ts:

```
    import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
    import { NavController, AlertController, reorderArray } from ‘ionic- 
    angular’;

    import { TodoProvider } from “…/…/providers/todo/todo”;
    import { ArchivedTodosPage } from “…/archived-todos/archived-todos”;

    @Component({
    selector: ‘page-home’,
    templateUrl: ‘home.html’
    })
    export class HomePage {
    public todos = [];

    public reorderIsEnabled = false;
    constructor(private todoProvider: TodoProvider, public navCtrl: 
    NavController, private alertController : AlertController, public 
    archivedtodosPage : ArchivedTodosPage) {
    this.todos = this.todoProvider.getTodos();
    }

    goToArchivePage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(ArchivedTodosPage);
    }

    toggleReorder(){
    this.reorderIsEnabled = !this.reorderIsEnabled;
    }

    itemReordered($event){
    reorderArray(this.todos, $event);
    }

    openTodoAlert(){
    let addTodoAlert = this.alertController.create({
    title: “Add A Todo”,
    message: “Enter your Todo”,
    inputs: [
    {
    type: “text”,
    name: “addTodoInput”
    }
    ],
    buttons: [
    {
    text: “Cancel”
    },
    {
    text: “Add Todo”,
    handler: (inputData)=> {
    let todoText;
    todoText = inputData.addTodoInput;
    this.todoProvider.addTodo(todoText);

                   }
                 }
                ]
          });
          addTodoAlert.present();
    }

    }
```

home.html:

```
    the Real Todo Edit Done
         </ion-icon>
       </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    {{todo}}
              </ion-icon>
            </button>

          </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>



    </ion-list>
     <button ion-fab (click)="gotoArchivePage()">

      <ion-icon name="archive">

      </ion-icon>

     </button>
```

app.module.ts:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from ‘@angular/platform-browser’;
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from ‘ionic-angular’;
    import { SplashScreen } from ‘@ionic-native/splash-screen’;
    import { StatusBar } from ‘@ionic-native/status-bar’;

    import { MyApp } from ‘./app.component’;
    import { HomePage } from ‘…/pages/home/home’;
    import { TodoProvider } from “…/providers/todo/todo”;
    import { HttpClientModule } from ‘@angular/common/http’;
    import { ArchivedTodosPage } from “…/pages/archived-todos/archived-todos”;

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ArchivedTodosPage
    ],
    imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ArchivedTodosPage
    ],
    providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TodoProvider
    ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts CODE:

```
    import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
    import { Platform } from ‘ionic-angular’;
    import { StatusBar } from ‘@ionic-native/status-bar’;
    import { SplashScreen } from ‘@ionic-native/splash-screen’;

    import { ArchivedTodosPage } from “…/pages/archived-todos/archived-todos”;

    import { HomePage } from ‘…/pages/home/home’;
    @Component({
    templateUrl: ‘app.html’
    })
    export class MyApp {
    rootPage:any = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
    SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
    });
    }
    }
```

I will be most grateful for your assistance as I have been struggling to get this issue fixed for quite sometime now

Comment: I did a bit of re-formatting of your input, and made the question more clear. But: this is way too much input. You should look into [mcve] and rework your question to contain a minimal, complete example. Dont expect people dig through so many lines of code. Especially tiven the fact that you more or less just dumped your code here. You should at least spent the time required to decently indent your code snippets (so that blocks/loops/... are more indented).

Comment: Thanks for having responded. All the same, it is not as you have stated, the code is way more than what i posted, i would not agree to you saying that I just dumped my code. I am not at the moment as you are, very conversant with coding. I am learning everyday, every single day. Please be more considerate and understanding with your language. Thank you :) . Nevertheless, more importantly I am sincerely grateful for your kind assistance.

Comment: I agree, there are people dumping worse stuff. But still: many parts of your js code are almost not at all indented. Therefore the input is way harder to read than necessary. Seriously: such details matter big time.

Comment: Thank you. @GhostCat, are there like any websites or links to resources which can help me clean up my code as you suggested in case I have another question. Considering you are a guru at coding?

Comment: Most IDEs such as intellij or atom should have auto formatter features that also indent code in a meaningful way. That would be a good starting point. You then paste that into the edit window here. Maybe you have to select the code and click the {} braces icon. That will indent by 4 to display as code. You should also use the preview window to ensure you are happy with the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sincerely grateful.